# Sum count data in a dataframe based on the size of an associated numeric variable

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I have a data frame with data as follows (although my data set is much bigger)

```
ID  Count  Size
1   1      35
1   2      42
1   2      56
2   3      25
2   5      52
2   2      62
```

etc....

I would like to extract the total count for each ID but split for when the size variable is either <50 or <=50

So far I have done this to get the cumulative count based on the unique id

```
cbind(aggregate(Count~ID, sum, data=df)
```

To produce this

```
ID Count
1  5
2  10
```

But I want to produce something like this instead

```
ID  <50  >=50
1   3    2
2   3    7
```

I've tried searching on how best to do this and am sure it is really simple but I'm struggling on how best to achieve this...any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', we get the `sum` of 'Count' based on the logical indexes ('Size < 50`,`Size >=50`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(`<50` = sum(Count[Size <50]), 
            `>=50` = sum(Count[Size>=50])) , by = ID]
#   ID <50 >=50
#1:  1   3    2
#2:  2   3    7
```

---

A similar option with `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(`<50` = sum(Count[Size <50]),
             `>=50` = sum(Count[Size>=50]))
```

NOTE: It is better to name the columns as `less50`, `greaterthanEq50` instead of the names suggested in the expected output.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was after!

Answer (score 0):

Continue your idea, you can actually `aggregate` on `df[df$Size<50,]` instead of `df`, and do this again for >=50 then merge.

```
d1 = aggregate(Count~ID,sum,data=df[df$Size<50,])
d2 = aggregate(Count~ID,sum,data=df[df$Size>=50,])
merge(d1,d2,by="ID",all=TRUE)
```

This is just based on what you already did, but not the best I guess..